# Understanding HTML5 data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colors, html5-canvas

I am fairly new to javascript/jQuery, however I am making all efforts to understand what I am doing. I was inspired by [diesel's site](http://www.diesel.com/). On [this site](http://www.diesel.com/), data attributes are used for the text blocks on the home page. `data-color`. I want to achieve this function on [my site](http://www.lybstore.com/index.php). Being able to change the color of each block per entry, as the user scrolls down the page, it triggers differently.

I have come on here for help as I haven't seen any tutorial in relation to the functionality I am trying to achieve. Does anyone know how this can be done? I believe this would be helpful for those that want to execute the same or a similar functionality.

```
getColorMod: function(color, val) {
    var hexToRgb = function(hex) {
        var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
        return result ? [parseInt(result[1], 16), parseInt(result[2], 16), parseInt(result[3], 16)] : false;
    }
    var array = hexToRgb(color),
    r = parseFloat(array[0] + val),
    g = parseFloat(array[1] + val),
    b = parseFloat(array[2] + val),
    rgb = array ? {
        r: r >= 250 ? 200 : r,
        g: g >= 250 ? 200 : g,
         b: b >= 250 ? 200 : b
    } : false;

    return 'rgb(' + rgb.r + ', ' + rgb.g + ', ' + rgb.b + ')';
},
```

Comment: I don't see any canvas on page. All effects done via css3 transitions. Use web-debugger (for example webinspector built in Chrome) to view how exactly.

Comment: @Tommi i think you have misunderstood my question. I have edited it slightly.

Comment: data- attributes is just a way to store information. Browser don't use it automatically, but you can use it from your own js code.

Answer (score 6):

The HTML5 data attribute is there simply for the purpose of storing additional information within html elements. I've used it when printing various sets of data programmatic-ly to include information like user account numbers.  bits of data that you may want to access with javascript or jquery

**You can see a [great documentation/tutorial here on the HTML5 data attribute by webtutsplus](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute/)**

The data-attribute is interesting because you can define one as anything you like:

```
     data-[NAME]="[VALUE]"
     data-color="blue"
     data-price="$19.96"
```

The more recent versions of jQuery also have a built in easy to use function to deal specifically with [**getting and setting HTML5 data-attributes - documentation here**](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Imagine some hypothetical html:

```
     <span id="fluxCapacitor" data-gigawats="1.21"></span>
```

Calling the .data handler on our flux capacitor jquery element would return "1.21"

```
     $('#fluxCapacitor').data('gigawats'); // "1.21"
```

And you could use two parameter functionality for setting your flux capacitor to over 9000 gigawats.

```
     $('#fluxCapacitor').data('gigawats', "over 9000");
```

Resulting in:

```
     <span id="fluxCapacitor" data-gigawats="over 9000"></span>
```

---

*edit: adjusted my power levels for historical accuracy.*

Comment: -1 for not knowing flux capacitors only require 1.21 gigawatts, and  Over 9000 only applies to alien power levels. j/k, I modded this up, it's a great answer otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="bg">
    <div style="transition: background 500ms ease; -webkit-transition: background 500ms ease; background-color: rgb(25, 30, 36);"></div>
</div>
```

using library of your choice

This seems to be the way Diesel is performing the color transitions.

```
var $bodyBg = $('<div />'),
$bg = $('<div />').addClass('bg').append($bodyBg),
$arrow = $('<span />').addClass('arrow');

this.$navs.append($bg).append($arrow);

this.$navs
.on('hide', function() {
    // hide navigation bar
    $(this).addClass('hide');
})
.on('show', function() {
    // show navigation bar
    $(this).removeClass('hide');
})
.on('changeColor', $.proxy(function(e, color) {

    var $elm = $(e.currentTarget),
        $bg = $elm.find('.bg div');

    if (Modernizr.csstransforms && Modernizr.csstransitions) {
        // css3 transition
        $bg.css({
            transition: 'background 500ms ease',
            backgroundColor: this.getColorMod(color, 12)
        });
    } else {
        // no css3 transition support
        $bg.css({
            backgroundColor: this.getColorMod(color, 12)
        });
    }

}, this))
.trigger('hide')
.appendTo(this.$el);
```

Comment: you've misunderstood my question